# Running Java7 in Chrome for Mac OS X (requires 64bit?

Tags: macos, google-chrome, 64-bit, java

My home banking system requires Java for logging onto the bank - see https://www.nemid.nu/ for a description of the system (in Danish only).

This worked fine in Chrome under Mac OS X until recently when in suddenly required a new download of the Java plug-in. Unfortunately, Oracle gives me the following message:

> Chrome does not support Java 7. Java 7 runs only on 64-bit browsers and Chrome is a 32-bit browser.
>
> If you download Java 7, you will not be able to run Java content in Chrome and will need to use a 64-bit browser (such as Safari or Firefox) to run Java content within a browser. Additionally, installing Java 7 will disable the ability to use Apple Java 6 on your system.

Note that I cannot uninstall Java 7 from my Mac as this is used for my job.

What can I do now - besides using Safari for my home banking? I cannot find a 64-bit Chrome and although Chrome should [support it](http://www.chromium.org/developers/design-documents/64-bit-support), there does not seem to be [any plans for an official release](http://www.quora.com/Why-is-Chrome-for-Mac-not-64-bit-yet).

[Migrated from [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12501356/796559)..]

Comment: The comment on the un-migrated question is pretty spot-on. If you need to use chrome instead of Safari for your banking, you might look into a virtual machine.

Comment: The problem is, I have other problems with Safari, so if I can avoid it, then I would really prefer that...

Comment: Running a virtualized copy of windows or OS X or linux would probably be your best bet then. Anything else is likely to involve you getting your hands very dirty with a compiler and an open-sourced JDK or waiting until the x64 mac build is completed.

Comment: luckily for you (and everyone in DK) in the long run you won't need Java to use Nem-ID [Read-here](http://www.version2.dk/artikel/her-er-nemid-til-javascript-52735) (danish)

Answer (score 21, accepted):

I noticed a workaround mentioned in the Chrome forum.

you can temporarily [re-enable the Apple-provided Java SE 6 applet plug-in and Web Start functionality](http://support.apple.com/kb/HT5559) which supposedly can let you re-use java 6 again in chrome.

Found via Chrome forum thread "[Where can i download Chrome 64-bit?](http://productforums.google.com/forum/#!msg/chrome/qNC-G2gSQb4/RAw6SXkyZRsJ)"

Comment: I had the same problem and it worked like a charm for me. Thanks

Comment: PURE AWESOME! Thanks a lot ++1. Java working finally in Google Chrome with OSX 10.9.4, earlier used just firefox for Java.

Answer (score 3):

If your situation is that you upgraded to 10.8.2 but already had a functioning javaws that no longer launches when needed, you can get away with just step 5 of the [instructions](http://support.apple.com/kb/HT5559) pointed to by Jesper Rønn-Jensen:

```
sudo ln -sf /System/Library/Frameworks/JavaVM.framework/Commands/javaws /usr/bin/javaws
```

Comment: I haven't "upgraded" to 10.8.x - and probably never will as there are too many changes I don't really like :-)