# Java stopped working with Chrome since OS X 10.8.2

Tags: java, macos, google-chrome

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Running Java7 in Chrome for Mac OS X (requires 64bit?](https://superuser.com/questions/477182/running-java7-in-chrome-for-mac-os-x-requires-64bit)

After I upgrade my macbook pro to OS X 10.8.2 (java upgraded to 7 at same time), Chrome couldn't run Java applet. When I try to open a page containing Java applet, it tells to install java plugin. Even I re-install Java following the guide, problem is still same. But Safari works properly with Java. My Chrome version is 22.0.1229.94.

Dose anybody encounter same problem? Is this a unknown issue? Is there any solution?

Comment: Hava look at http://superuser.com/q/477182/87274

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's because Chrome is a 32 bit browser, which is not supported by JRE 7. From [their FAQ](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/webnotes/install/mac/mac-install-faq.html):

> Q: Should I install the JRE or the JDK?
>
> A: If you plan to run Java applications, install the Java Runtime Environment (JRE). The JRE is also referred to as Oracle Java. Once you have installed the JRE, you can launch Java applets and applications by double-clicking JAR files, JNLP files, and via the browser. Note that 32-bit browsers, such as Firefox in 32-bit mode, and Chrome, are not supported by the JRE.

Answer (score 2):

You're running a 64-bit JVM and Chrome is only available in 32-bit varieties. You will have to use another browser or downgrade your JVM.